# How do I use and/or instead of if/cond?

Tags: scheme, lisp, r5rs

I'm new to Scheme programming and I've gotten this task that I just can't find out how to work correctly. I'm supposed to define a procedure with one parameter (a number). If the number is positive I want `1` to be returned, `-1` if the number is negative and `0` if it is 0, using only and/or. If and cond is not allowed. I only get **#t** or **#f** returned, but you see that's not what I want. Any help or pointers is appreciated

Comment: Show your code.what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

You can solve your problem if you look at the following equivalence, **valid when every `expj` has a value different from `#f`**:

```
(cond (test1 exp1)         (or (and test1 exp1)
      (test2 exp2)             (and test2 exp2)
      ...               ≡      ...
      (testn expn)             (and testn expn)
      (else expn+1))           expn+1)
```

Since the function that gets the sign of a number can simply be written in this way:

```
(define (sign x)
  (cond ((> x 0) +1)
        ((< x 0) -1)
        (else 0)))
```

after applying the above equivalence, since every result is an integer, different from `#f`, this function becomes equal to the solution proposed also in another answer:

```
(define (sign x)
  (or (and (> x 0) +1)
      (and (< x 0) -1)
      0))
```

So, which is the reason of the above equivalence? It depends on the fact that `and` evaluates its arguments in turn; as soon as one of them is `#f`, it stops by returning `#f`, otherwise returns its *last* argument (and this explains the single branches `(and testj expj)`); while `or` evaluates its arguments in turn; as soon as one of them is *not* `#f`, it stops by returning it, otherwise returns its *last* argument (and this explains the chain `(or (and ...) (and ...) ... expn+1)`).

Comment: This equivalence is only correct if all the expN are true.

Answer (score 1):

```
(define test 
    (lambda (n)
        (or (and (< n 0) -1)
            (and (= n 0) 0)
            1)))
```

Part of the trick is understanding that *and*, if everything evaluates to true, will return the last item it evaluated, while *or* will return the first thing that successfully evaluates to true. The other part is realizing that everything except for #f is considered "true."

Answer (score 0):

The transformation of `and` is seen in the report but to not include the actual macros it's basically this:

```scm
; only one argument
(and a) ; ===>
a

; one of more
(and a b ...) ; ==>
(if a
    (and b ...)
    #f)
```

All arguments must be evaluate to a positive value and the last value is the result, else `#f`. It short circuits so when something is `#f` the rest of the expressions are never evaluated.

For `or` is like this:

```scm
(or a) ; ==>
a

(or a b ...) ; ==>
(let ((a-value a))
  (if a-value
      a-value
      (or b ...)))
```

The first argument that does not evaluate to `#f` gets returned. If all values are `#f` the last `#f` will be the result.

Thus if you want:

```scm
(if a b c)                 ; ==>

(let ((tmpa a))            
  (or (and atmpa b)        
      (and (not atmpa) c)) ; not part only important if b can be #f
```

I use `let` to prevent evaluating the same expression several times. eg. if you had one that printed something like `(begin (display "hello") #f)` or it's an expensive calculation then it's necessary or else you can just substitute the variable with the expression. eg. the last would become:

```scm
(or (and a b)
    (and (not a) c))
```

That transformed back with no temporary variables become:

```scm
(if (if a b #f)
    (if a b #f)
    (if (not a) c #f))
```

If b is `#f` value, then the result is `#f` because of the last `if`. Thus everytime `a` is true `b` is the result. Everytime it's false, `c` is the answer. Thus

```scm
(if a b c)
```

So imagine you want to return the first true value in a list.

```scm
(define (first-true lst)
  (and (not (null? lst))
       (car lst)
       (first-true (cdr lst))))
```